# inserting millisecond into mysql from c#

Tags: c#, mysql, date-formatting

I am trying to insert millisecond into data type of datetime(6) in MySQL using c#.

here is my code:

```
 MySqlCommand myCommand4 = new MySqlCommand("Insert into Test_OrderRecord values('" + OrderID + "','" + customerCode + "','" + customer + "','" + TelComboBox.Text + "','" + LicenseComboBox.Text + "','" +
                          DriverComboBox.Text + "','" + AddressComboBox.Text + "','" + LocationTypeComboBox.Text + "','" + PickupComboBox.Text + "','" + CustomerTypeLabel.Text + "','" +
                       Convert.ToDecimal(TotalPriceLabel.Text) + "','" + status + "','" + note + "','" + sandReceiptNo + "','" + createtiming + "','" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "')", myConnection);
                    myCommand4.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

the `createtiming` is created with

```
createtiming = OrderDateTimePicker.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:ffffff");
```

I have read the value of `createtiming` before it inserts into MySQL, and it does contain milliseconds, however, when I do

```
SELECT * FROM SaveFundDevelopmentDB.Test_OrderDetails
```

on MySQL, I only see time like

```
2015-08-27 15:33:04.000000
```

While the time should be like 2015-08-27 15:33:04.123456 something like this.

I am trying to Order the table by using this `createtiming` to the very millisecond.

How should I get this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out [this](https://blogs.oracle.com/MySqlOnWindows/entry/milliseconds_value_support_on_datetime) tutorial with parameterized queries.
1. Ceate a command object :

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
```

2. Set the command text with parameters similar to one in the tutorial.
3. Define a parameter :
   `MySqlParameter dt  = new MySqlParameter();
   dt.ParameterName = "@createTiming";
   dt.MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.DateTime;<br>
   dt.Value = "2015-08-27 15:33:04.123456";<br>
   cmd.Parameters.Add(dt);`
4. Call cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @veljasije Thanks for your feedback.